# CSS position - partly overlapping div

Tags: html, css

I have basic CSS layout issue. DIV2 goes up by 150px and overlap partly DIV1. I have a problem with placing DIV3 just under DIV2. I could do it applying the same CSS as in DIV2 to DIV3, but thats not what i'm looking for, as they are many other divs under, and it seem i will have to do the same to all others. There must be something to reset positions. I hope i explain myself clearly. Height of DIV2 has to be flexible too (mobile).

Visual graph:

[image]

CSS DIV2:

```
position: relative;
top: -150px;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Comment: shouldn't your second `div2` class be actually `div3` ? you have declared `div2` class twice in your shared HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-top` instead of `top` property in CSS. And the rest divs below `div2` will automatically follow.

And if still it doesn't works, Share the working fiddle of your code.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}
.div1 {
  background: red;
}
.div3 {
  background: green;
}
.div2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `div2`, although it's not considered a best practice:

`margin-bottom: -150px`

```css
.div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  height: 150px;  
}

.div1 {
  background: red;  
}

.div2 {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  margin-bottom: -75px;
}

.div3 {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Comment: what will be the best practice?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer that's showing that a negative margin is working.

Comment: I think I would try to place `div2` inside `div1` and position it absolutely there